# Flipkart Product API - How to get top selling product from the category

Tags: api, feed, flipkart-api

According to the flipkart product api we can get the top selling products from the category, but I'm not able to get the top selling products. According to the flipkart following is the sample url which return top selling products.

https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/topFeeds/fnkygygma/category/reh/55ab6c2673a4773ffb8e4019.json?expiresAt=1452881213871&sig=1c4c5111b6b014a71a17b229e6df6afc&inStock=true

I have following queries.
what is reh in the URL?
what is "55ab6c2673a4773ffb8e4019" in the URL is this category name, how I'll get the category name like this for other categories.
As I know "expiresAt" comes from flipkart, how I can generate this myself?
How I can generate "sig"?

it will be really helpful if someone answer for this.

Comment: It seems someting is missing from flipkart site. Those URL are generated (example `https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/fnkygygma.json` generate productFeeds).  But For topFeeds, I did not find anything. You will need to contact Flipkart about that.

Comment: you need to contact them for api access

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you would have to query their database for the ID of the category that you want the top products from, and then use it in the URI when requesting the feed.

The documentation doesn't show "reh" in the URI so I'm guessing that sample is for testing purposes.

I found the section that says, "The Product Feed Listing API provides the full list of categories present in the catalogue."
The URI is: https://affiliate.flipkart.com/api-docs/af_prod_ref.html#product-feed-listing-api

You do realize that there is a new version of the API? It's 1.1

The documentation says that you have to request a list of the categories with this URI: https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/<trackingId>.json

Insert your ID where it says <trackingId> and it will return a list of the categories along with metaData.

The categories live in the apiListings section of the JSON response.

Comment: I do get the id of the category through  https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/api/<trackingId>.json. I can access the products of a category through https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/feeds/agnelvish/category/ckf-czl.json But https://affiliate-api.flipkart.net/affiliate/1.0/topFeeds/agnelvish/category/tyy-4io.json gives me 404 error

Comment: It seems like there is an error with their documentation or the service.

Comment: @AgnelVishal it seems flipkart no more provides affiliate member registration. Is it so? If yes, then can we use there [APIs](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/index.html#) without affiliate membership. Also what are other options to obtain information about specific product on flipkart programattically? Are we left only with web scrapping (in the absense of access to there API due to no affiliate membership)?

Comment: @AbrahamLuna  it seems flipkart no more provides affiliate member registration. Is it so? If yes, then can we use there [APIs](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/index.html#) without affiliate membership. Also what are other options to obtain information about specific product on flipkart programattically? Are we left only with web scrapping (in the absense of access to there API due to no affiliate membership)?

Comment: Seems the product APIs are not working. Is anyone successful in using these APIs?